# Use PHP to parse or split a CSV without reading into memory

Tags: php, parsing, csv, split, sequential

I have a product feed from a vendor, the file comes as a 100mb .gz file.  I use PHP to unpack the file to a 1gb .csv file.  My server has no problem with the unpacking, however, I want to grab the information from the .csv and drop it into a MySQL database.

The .csv contains about 240,000 rows, with about 20 - 25 comma delimited fields.  The trouble is that my hosting provider doesn't allow me to load a file this large into memory for processing.

Does anyone know of a way I can either split the .csv into smaller files (maybe 100mb each), either while unpacking from the original .gz, or is there a way for me to read the information contained within the .csv without loading the whole file into memory?

Comment: [`SplFileObject::fgetcsv`](http://php.net/SplFileObject.fgetcsv) or plain [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv), for opening even with `compress.zlib://`. Or use Mysqls [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv).